# How to fetch dynamic data for dynamic table from database?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dynamic-data

I am dealing with e-commerce admin panel. I designed dynamic table that lists customer details for admin panel. User can add new columns to table or remove.
[image: The table in admin-panel]

So I must fetch data from database dynamically. It must just fetch data in the columns that the user selected. By using Entity-Framework, how does I fetch data dynamically? There are total 47 columns and in different tables. Also, I designed all database operations by using stored-procedures. You know that there are entity classes to execute the procedures in EF. What is the best option to solve this problem?

For example, I create a stored-procedure that execute dynamically, but I can't match with entity class in EF. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can't do it using Entity Framework. Entity Framework have typed models (POCO). You might need a custom solution, may be try a datasource of type `IDictionary<string, object>` which can be converted to `ExpandoObject` available in C#. But that also depends if your CMS supports it.